# Derive mechanical pressure from strain energy density

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, stress-strain, navier-stokes

Similarly to thermodynamic pressure, when we have:

$$P_{therm} = (\frac{\partial U}{\partial V})_{S}$$

Can we define the mechanical pressure for a fluid as:

$$P_{mech} = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial(-\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})}$$

Where $\psi$ is the strain energy density functional, which is defined as:

$$\psi = \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{S}$$

Where $\mathbf{P}$ is the Cauchy stress tensor defined as for an incompressible Newtonian fluid: $$\mathbf{P} = -P_{mech}\mathbf{I}+2\mu\mathbf{S}$$

and $\mathbf{S}$ is the strain rate tensor defined as: $$\mathbf{S} = \frac{1}{2}(\nabla \mathbf{u}+(\nabla \mathbf{u})^{T})$$

I know it works fine for incompressible flow. But interestingly I didn't find this derivation in analogy to thermodynamic in any text book. Any idea or suggeston is appreciated.

Comment: Incompressible homogeneous fluid has $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}=0$. How can you take a derivative w.r.t. that quantity?

Comment: @Deep You are right, I could think of it as this limit: $\lim_{\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \rightarrow 0} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})} = P_{mech}$, what's your opinion?

Comment: This way of defining pressure is new to me. May be you are on to something.

Comment: @Deep My intention is to understand what mechanical pressure really means. In fact, I know from solid mechanics that we could even derive the Cauchy stress tensor ($\mathbf{P}$) from strain energy density as: $\mathbf{P} = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \mathbf{S}}$ where $\mathbf{S}$ is the strain tensor.

Comment: I wanted to know two things here. First: Is it possible to use same concept for fluids instead of solids and replace $\psi$ with strain rate energy density and $\mathbf{S}$  with strain rate tensor to get Cauchy stress tensor. Second, what if I take derivative with respect to trace of strain rate tensor ($\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}$) which implies its isotropic interaction to get isotropic mechanical pressure maybe?! Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Both solid and fluid mechanics form the common subject of continuum mechanics. But the two differ in that, in a solid work done by stresses can be stored purely as strain energy, but in a fluid it goes into kinetic energy of the fluid and into viscous dissipation. So to call $\psi$ a "strain energy" density is inappropriate even as an analogy, I think.

Comment: Since your intention is to "understand what mechanical pressure really means" let me assert that the concept of pressure in fluid mechanics is quite intuitive and physical. All you need to accept is that if you imagine  an area element inside the fluid then fluid on one side of that area can exert a force on the fluid lying on the other side of the area. If you take a small volume of fluid in the shape of a sphere, then pressure is nothing but the average normal force acting on the sphere's surface and is usually compressive.